# Textjoin based on multiple columns and a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, textjoin

HI I would like to know what is the formula to textjoin/concate below information? summary of status

[image]

I have tried to use this but not sure how to include the second column in and have unique values

`=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,(UNIQUE(IF(I6:I17=J20,K6:K17,""))))` - only one column

if include the array, will not have unique value, duplicate, and actual requirement the column will not be adjacent.

I'm kinda hopeless with formula still learning.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: So you are looking to get values from `First Status` right?

Comment: will be from first and second status combine and do not have repeating values. so for example. if first status only have old and new and second status have old, new, renew. The final results will have old, new and renew extract from the two columns. For now I only know how to extract from one column. I need from two columns.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=LET(a,UNIQUE(A2:A12),HSTACK(a,BYROW(a,LAMBDA(b,TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(C2:E12,A2:A12=b),1,3))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the formula but, is there a way not to combine the G and H output? and also (A&B)? Only want it to show as A (fix text) : (output from both status1&status2-unique).

Comment: @fsfoodie please update your question to include a clear sample of what you mean here

Comment: Have A in G2 and "New, Old, Renew" in H2 with formula depending on what's in G (at least, that's how I'm reading his explanation)